# ADF using EL in Java code

Tags: jsf, el, oracle-adf

I've got a main page that displays number of records, when I click on create, it should navigate to create form (another JSF), where on Submitting the new record, it should navigate back to main page and display all the records including the new one.

I've been able to achieve the navigation using navigation rules in `adfc-config` file. And I've created Action method (beans) that returns expected string used in navigation.

What challenge I'm facing now is on button click, I can invoke only one method (`action`), which has to return the expected string for navigation. Or I can use EL that does the refresh. So I'm either able to Refresh the page after creating a new record, or able to Navigate. Can't do both. (Usage of `actionListener` won't work, because `actionListener` works before `action`, my requirement needs sequential execution.

Is there a way I can use EL in my Java code? So that I can put it right after the record creation and before return string?

Some method that executes method specified by EL, where I just have to pass the EL as a string?

Update: Both Query (display) and Insert are API calls.

Comment: You can find some useful methods [here](http://www.adftips.com/2010/10/adf-ui-adfutil-class-to-evaluate-set.html)

Comment: JD uses EL 2.2. The code mentioned in those links use EL 3.0

Comment: If you are using commit on the transaction , it should already be updated in the your main page? I do not see a need to refresh though

Comment: @Sam, well the page is rendered from a different source. It's basically API call for query and insert.

Answer (score 0):

From what you're saying, you're using the Unbounded task flow `adfc-config` to build your navigation business logic. This is not right! The Unbounded task flow's primary purpose is to define the base structure of your site. For example, on your Homepage, if you have a link for "Create Department" and another one for "Add Employee", there would be only 2 simple navigation rules to link to those independent pages.

To achieve your goal, what you need is a Bounded task flow and a few page fragments. The picture below is an actual Bounded taskflow in one of the applications I worked on. Let's take it as an example.

[image]

The main feature of a Bounded task flow is that all fragments in the same task flow will share a common data control (i.e. all fragments will see the same set of data). As you can see from the picture above, my starting page is a Search page for Corporate cards, where I'll display all records based on what users search for.

On this Search page, I also have a Create button to allow users to create a new record, which would lead to the Details page (which is also the page to edit current records). Once users commit the transaction on the Details page, they will be redirected back to the Search page by following the `viewCorporateCard` navigation rule. Since both the Search page and the Details page share the same data control (the same iterator to be precise), users will automatically see the new record on top of the Search page when they're back here. You don't have to do anything manually to achieve this.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

To pass EL value as string

```
this.setvalueToExpression("#{bindings.Orderno.inputValue}",
                              "sample");//pass string value

public void setvalueToExpression(String el, Object val) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    ExpressionFactory expressionFactory =
        facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
    ValueExpression exp =
        expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, el,
                                                Object.class);
    exp.setValue(elContext, val);
}
```